# Magento 2 ElasticSeach reindexing issue

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Using Magento ver. 2.2.5

I've following

```
$ composer info | grep elastic
elasticsearch/elasticsearch                       v6.7.2    PHP Client for Elasticsearch
magento/module-elasticsearch                      100.2.4   N/A

$curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "ThinkPad",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Bxpu3ocET3iHvSax1nIzgw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.4.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "fc0eeb6e2c25915d63d871d344e3d0b45ea0ea1e",
    "build_date" : "2019-10-22T17:16:35.176724Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.2.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

In Magento Search

```
 catalog/search/engine =>elasticsearch5
```

When I try to do following

```
$php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2016-03-09 00:00:00 2016-03-09 00:00:00 2016-03-09 00:00:00 2016-03-09 00:00:00 2016-03-09 00:00:00 2016-03-09 00:00:00 2016-03-09 00:00:00) at position 20 (2): Double date specification
```

2nd Time

```
$php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Could not convert [custom_layout_update.index] to boolean"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Could not convert [custom_layout_update.index] to boolean","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse value [no] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."}},"status":400}
```

Is this version compatibility issue or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up as following, It has started working.

Magento **2.5.2**

ES Services **2.4.6**

ES PHP Client : **6.1**

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you recived this error, hope you'll find answer in here. 
https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues